# Tomcat não atualiza arquivos

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet

O problema é o seguinte, toda vez que eu altero um arquivo (`index` por exemplo), reinicio o `tomcat(v7)` e aperto F5 no navegador, ele fica na mesma, não atualiza nada, ou seja acaba ficando na versão anterior....

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: O Tomcat deve estar fazendo cache dos arquivos. Tente fazer [isto](http://luizricardo.org/2012/09/evite-reiniciar-o-tomcat-6-e-deixe-a-inicializacao-mais-rapida/). Se funcionar eu adiciono uma resposta aqui.

Comment: Pode ser cache, se estiver usando o eclipse, click com o botão direito em cima do servidor e va em clear, reinicie o servidor e tente novamente.

Comment: @rray eu já tinha feito isso... Mas não deu certo....

Comment: Também não foi @utluiz

Answer (score 1):

Naldson esse problema pode acontecer por vários motivos, vou te dar algumas opções pra ver se resolve seu problema, vamos lá.

1° veja se seu projeto esta com Build marcado como automático, no eclipse fica em Project > BuildAutomatically. Se não estiver marque, isso facilita um pouco.

2° Quando vc modifica algo na sua view, lá na aba servers esta mostrando Synchronized ? se estiver mostrando republish clique com botão direito e selecione a opção publish, vá no navegador e clique em F5, veja se funcionou.

3° Tente apertar Ctrl + F5 para atualizar, veja se funcionou.

Caso não de certo, veja se o terminal exibe algum log de erro.